# jQuery Mobile loading ui-icon-alt

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to load the alternate icon set but I'm not sure how. i've tried adding `ui-icon-alt` as a class and no luck, tried changing the data-icon to data-icon-alt, tried alt-arrow-l,... how do you load it?

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">
    Back
</a>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the black icons?

Comment: @codaniel yes the black icons. I don't want to replace the white ones, I'd like to use both icon sets in my app

Comment: Did you find a solution while still keeping the default icon sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the default ui-icon class with this

```
.ui-icon{
    background-image: url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/images/icons-18-black.png)​;
}
```

Just be sure to place that after the JQM css file.

Answer (score 5):

How to load `ui-icon-alt` on any element:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l ui-icon-alt" data-iconpos="left">
    Back
</a>
```